# What does a 0-value transaction mean?

Tags: transactions

I‘ve received a transaction of (as I was told) a frozen account.
I shows an amount of 16ETH, but somehow the value of the transaction is Zero.
What does that mean?

Comment: It would help if you showed the transaction

Comment: 0x7c101b0a635d49544e91c87f5195809b94e68e9474ee6abfbfcd9bd2f0ea6033

Answer (score 1):

This is a scam. You havent been transferred actual ETH, but an ERC20 token named "ETH" (anyone can deploy a token contract and give it the name they want). The goal is to lure you into interacting with that contract (0x8C2a902544E2B7A65Dcf37e06405Fa37886e2F9a), which would probably steal your funds one way or another.

Comment: That is exactly what I feared!

Comment: Can I do something against that? Or do I have to do anything?

Comment: No need to do anything.

Comment: Yep, don't do anything @Alain. The goal is actually to get you "do something", like transfer the token away or try to sell it, that's how the scam works. Just let it sit there, as long as you don't do anything it can't do anything to you, every wallet on any chain gets this kind of tokens, you can't really prevent that.